# FDCAN in production mode cannot send messages

Tags: stm32, can-bus

I am using a STM32MP157C-DK2 board to communicate via CAN. To do this, I have created a program in STM32CubeIDE and set the FDCAN parameters:

[FDCAN configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aiIQF.png)

I have been testing in engineering mode and I was able to receive and send CAN messages (I have connected to an IXXAT device) using the following function in the main function:

```
/* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */
if(HAL_FDCAN_GetRxFifoFillLevel(&hfdcan1, FDCAN_RX_FIFO0) > 0)
{
    HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(GPIOF, GPIO_PIN_3);
    // Recoger mensaje de la cola
    if(HAL_FDCAN_GetRxMessage(&hfdcan1, FDCAN_RX_FIFO0, &RxHeader, RxData) != HAL_OK)
    {
        Error_Handler();
    }
    if(HAL_FDCAN_AddMessageToTxFifoQ(&hfdcan1, &TxHeader, TxData))
    {
        Error_Handler();
    } */
}
```

Then the tests have been carried out in production mode. In this case, first the A7 processor is initialized and then the M4 processor program is started with the following commands (Core_Communication is the name of the program):

```
echo Core_Communication_CM4.elf > /sys/class/remoteproc/remoteproc0/firmware
echo start > /sys/class/remoteproc/remoteproc0/state
```

In this case, I try to send CAN messages through IXXAT but I get the following error:

```
ACK error
```

Is there a parameter that I have to configure?

Comment: If you send a message from the IXXAT listener but get an ACK error, then it sounds as if something is wrong with the reception and it's not necessarily a software problem. Ensure that the bus is correctly terminated and measure the RX pin of the transceiver with your scope to see that data is coming out from it.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer @Lundin. Could it be that since the FDCAN clock of the STM32MP1 board is not activated, the IXXAT is not capable of sending a can message and therefore the ACK error appears?

Comment: If you have no clock you wouldn't be able to do anything at all.

Comment: I am thinking that it may be that since the board's FDCAN clock is not activated, when the message is sent by the IXXAT device, it gives an ACK error. Thank you very much for the help @Lundin ;)